# Displaying an image using a class on pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am new to using pygame and I am trying to make a class that will display an image on pygame. I want to make it so I can eventually put multiple images onto the screen and move them around the screen. At the moment I just want to display the image on the screen using this format. Can anyone show me code to do that and explain why?

```
import pygame 
import time 
import random 

pygame.init() 

display_width = 1000 
display_height = 750  

Gameplay = False 

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height)) 
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #Starts auto clock updater

background_image = pygame.image.load("Image/Background.jpg").convert() 
gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0, 0]) 

EnImg = pygame.image.load('Image\Enemy.gif') 

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,dx,dy,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = pygame.image.load('Image\Enemy.gif')
        self.image = image
        self.rect.x = dx
        self.rect.y = dy

    def update(self):
        pass

while not Gameplay: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    EnImg = Enemy(500,500,EnImg)
    EnImg.draw(screen)
    game_change()

    pygame.display.update() 
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: you have to assign image to `self.image` and then `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`

Comment: I get the error 
    'Enemy' object has no attribute 'draw'
After i make that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sprite` doesn't have `draw()` function but other functions (ie. [pygame.sprite.Group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)) use directly `self.image` and `self.rect` to draw this sprite.

You can create own function `draw()` to do the same

```
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

You don't have to load `Enemy.gif` two times. Do it inside `Enemy` class or outside and then use image as argument `Enemy( ..., image)` (or use filename `Enemy( ..., filename)` and load inside.)

---

It could look like this.

```
import pygame 

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1000 
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 750  
DISPLAY_SIZE = (DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, dx, dy, filename):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = dx
        self.rect.y = dy

        # - or shorter -
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=dx, y=dy)

        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.x -= 10
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 10
        if self.moving_up:
            self.rect.y -= 10
        if self.moving_down:
            self.rect.y += 10

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = False

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- fuctions --- (lower_case names)

    # empty

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init() 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY_SIZE) 

# - objects -

background_image = pygame.image.load("Image/Background.jpg").convert()

enemy = Enemy(500,500, 'Image/Enemy.gif')

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

gameplay = True

while gameplay: 

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameplay = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                gameplay = False

        # - objects event handle -
        enemy.handle_event(event)

    # - updates -

    enemy.update()

    # - draws -

    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    enemy.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update() 

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(60)

# - exit -

pygame.quit()
```

---

BTW: other [Pygame code templates](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/pygame/__template__) and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9niw.jpg)